# Selecting Active Nav in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a website and currently have a UserControl set to display the navigation

```
<div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="home" Text="Home" NavigateUrl="/Default.aspx" /></li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="about" Text="About Us" NavigateUrl="/AboutUs.aspx" /></li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="experience" Text="Experience" NavigateUrl="/Experience.aspx" /></li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="capabilities" Text="Capabilities" NavigateUrl="/Capabilities.aspx" /></li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="benefits" Text="Benefits" NavigateUrl="/Benefits.aspx" /></li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="contact" Text="Contact Us" NavigateUrl="/ContactUs.aspx" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I have two pages calling the UserControl.  Default.aspx and also Secondary.Master.  I need to know the best approach to be able to add "CssClass="Active" on either the parent `<li>` tag or the link itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the built-in ASP:Menu control. It has built-in capabilities to handle what you are trying to do.

Comment: Joining my suggestion with ataddeini's answer is a good way to go. His link provides great instruction on setting up a sitemap and linking it up with the .net Menu control. Makes site maintenance and the creation of site navigation super easy. You can even extend the sitemap to do some real crazy customizations, such as telling .Net to include certain controls on a page, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Is using a sitemap file for this an option for you?  If you do, you can utilize some of the built in providers/controls to help make things easier.  There's also the built-in ability to determine if a navigation element is the current page.

Scott Mitchell [has some good tutorials](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121516/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111605-1.aspx) on how to utilize these features.

Answer (score -1):

I added some code to the code behind on the UserControl

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetActiveNavLink();
    }

    private void SetActiveNavLink()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler.ToString().ToLower().Contains("default"))
        {
            home.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler.ToString().ToLower().Contains("about"))
        {
            about.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler.ToString().ToLower().Contains("experience"))
        {
            experience.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler.ToString().ToLower().Contains("capabilities"))
        {
            capabilities.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
        if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler.ToString().ToLower().Contains("benefits"))
        {
            benefits.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
        }
    }
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Now every time you add a new link to your menu, change the name of a page, etc, this code is going to break.  I'd seek a more flexible solution.

Comment: Thanks year and a half later