# change css class dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I would like change `<li>` css class dynamically. I am using asp.net masterpage. In below example If I click on `AboutUs.aspx` link on page load I want change `<li class="single">` to `<li class="active single">`.

How to do that?

```
 <div class="nav-collapse">
     <ul class="nav nav-pills">
           <li class="active single"><a href="Default.aspx">HOME
                 <i>company home</i>
                  </a>
            </li>
            <li class="single"><a href="AboutUs.aspx">About Us
                 <i>want to say</i>
                  </a>
            </li>
```

Comment: `$(this).addClass('active');` ???

Comment: Why don't you let ASP add that active class to the URL?

Comment: THis may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735171/selecting-active-nav-in-asp-net

Comment: When you load the page you have the links render with the class. You know what page is rendering the content through the Request object so it's just a matter of when you render the links to match the page to the href and change the color. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @scrappedcola have said, you don't have to do it in Javascript as this is totally doable from server side code. But if you insist, here are the steps:

1 You have to tell Javascript which item in the menu you want highlighted. Create unique identifiers for each menu item and tell the server side code to set that. For example:

```
<li class="single home">
    <a href="Default.aspx">HOME<i>company home</i></a>
</li>
<li class="single aboutus">
    <a href="AboutUs.aspx">About Us<i>want to say</i></a>
</li>
<script>
    var activeLink = 'aboutus';
</script>
```

2 Create and call the Javascript/jQuery function to change the CSS class:

```
$("." + activeLink).addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
$('li.single').click(function(){
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/HNKeA/1/.

Comment: it's going through a page load so this will work up until the page reloads

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.nav-collapse > ul > li > a').click( function(){
   $('li').removeClass('.active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('.active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav-pills a').click(function(){
    $('.nav-pills li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('li.single').click(function(){
      $(this).addClass('active');

  });
```

or

```
 $('li.single').click(function(){
         $(this).attr('class', 'active single');
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li:first").attr('class', 'newClass');
```

just change the selector accordingly.
This should change every li whats nested in ul